# ¿Cómo estructurar una cita con autor en HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Si tengo una cita como la siguiente en mi página web:

> "Pienso, luego existo"
>
> -René Descartes

¿Cuáles serían las etiquetas HTML5 adecuadas para representar esa cita y su autor? ¿Y cómo se estructurarían de manera correcta?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En HTML5 no se maqueta una cita de forma demasiado diferente a como se hacía en XHTML o HTML4. La estructura básica sería esta:

```html
 <blockquote>
    <p>"Pienso, luego existo"</p>
    <footer>
     <cite>René Descartes</cite>
    </footer>
  </blockquote>
```

Lo único distinto que vemos es el uso de la etiqueta `<footer>` que antes de HTML5 no existía, no es obligatorio usarla pero al estar el autor en una línea aparte es semánticamente la mejor opción.

Se podría añadir también el atributo `cite` (que sería una URL apuntando al origen de la cita) al `<blockquote>`, también un enlace en la etiqueta `<cite>` que lleve a una página sobre el autor o la obra según el caso.

Un punto de debate que hubo en su día fue que al principio en HTML5 la etiqueta `<cite>` era únicamente para el título de la obra pero en revisiones posteriores de la especificación eso cambió y se añadió la posibilidad de poner el nombre del autor, como se había hecho siempre.

Enlace a la etiqueta `<blockquote>` en la especificación de HTML5: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element

**PD:** Quizá también hayáis visto alguna vez usar `<cite>` para la cita en si pero no es la forma correcta de hacerlo, la función de `<cite>` siempre ha sido atribuir la autoría, la etiquetas para la cita son `<blockquote>` como elemento de bloque y `<q>` como elemento en línea.